# heroku local is not working

Tags: php, heroku

I'm trying to use Heroku local but it's not working as can be seen below. command prompt says 'vendor' is not recognized as an internal or external command...

```
C:\Users\owner\Desktop\php-getting-started> heroku local
[OKAY] Loaded ENV .env File as KEY=VALUE Format
15:23:09 web.1 | 'vendor' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
15:23:09 web.1 | operable program or batch file.
[DONE] Killing all processes with signal null
15:23:09 web.1 Exited with exit code 1
```

When I tried the first time, I got message saying like

> "No .env file found"

so I added `.env` file but I still cannot run locally.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: What is the error message you are getting when running Heroku local with the .env file created? Where was that file created? You're doing this on Windows 10 I take it?

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same issue today but managed to solve it by updating my Procfile from

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 web/
```

to

```
web: vendor\bin\heroku-php-apache2 web\
```

Hopefully this solves your issue too.

Comment: Thank you for the comment!
I tried it but didn't work for my case... still got the same error message

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

1. create a file `Procfile.windows` in the same location where `Procfile`
   file is.
2. add this command in `Procfile.windows` - `web: php -S localhost:8000 -t web/`
3. in terminal run `heroku local -f Procfile.windows`
4. visit `http://localhost:8000/`